# WKWebView cacheDisplayInRect screenshot in OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, wkwebview

I try to make a screenshot of WKWebView is OS X app and get completely empty screenshot. This code works fine with original WebView but does not works with WKWebView.

```
NSView *view = webView;
NSRect bounds = [view bounds];

NSBitmapImageRep *bitmapdata = [view bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplayInRect: bounds];
[webView cacheDisplayInRect: bounds toBitmapImageRep: bitmapdata];
```

Any ideas how to fix?

Answer (score 1):

Now you can take the screenshot using `WKWebView`.

[Apple added a new method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/2873260-takesnapshot?changes=latest_minor),

```
//iOS
func takeSnapshot(with snapshotConfiguration: WKSnapshotConfiguration?, 
completionHandler: @escaping (UIImage?, Error?) -> Void)

//macOS
func takeSnapshot(with snapshotConfiguration: WKSnapshotConfiguration?, 
completionHandler: @escaping (NSImage?, Error?) -> Void)
```

But its still in Beta.